# Добавить запятые в массивном тексте

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, codedom

Есть текст который заменяется через CodeDom компилятор.
Какой сейчас текст

```
string[] MyTextArray = new string[] { "TEST" };
```

нужно сделать чтобы было так после замены

```
string[] MyTextArray = new string[] { ".text", "test.*.123", "*.*" };
```

На форме (WinForms) лежит ListBox в него добавляются данные.
Затем я пытаюсь преобразовать с добавлением запятой

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   sb.AppendLine($"\"{ListBox1.Items[i]}\",");
}
if (sb.Length > 0) { sb.Length--; }
```

В итоге получаю такой результат:

```
string[] MyTextArray = new string[] { "\".text\",\r\n\".test.*.123\",\r" };
```

Через компилятор CodeDom просто делаю замену текстом `Replace("TEST", sb.ToString());`

Comment: `".text", "test.*.123", "*.*"` - это массив, который состоит из трех объектов, когда как `"\".text\",\r\n\".test.*.123\",\r"` - это строка, состоящая из ковычек, запятых и прочих экранированных символов. Вот тут вы и определитесь, что конкретно вам нужно, строка, или массив? Если массив, то зачем тогда вам `StringBuilder` (сборщик строки) и его метод `sb.AppendLine()` (добавить строку)? Замените его на простой `List<string>` и добавляйте циклом при помощи `.Add()` нужные объекты, без лишних запятых и др. (просто `ListBox1.Items[i]`), а дальше работайте с коллекцией.

Comment: Ну, я попробовал заменить на `List<string>`, но на выходе всё-ровно получается тоже самое так что не знаю что даже делать...